# Looking for a way to script a settings change in Preference Panel

Tags: macos

Background info:
I have a M-Audio Firewire soundcard that uses an external midi clock and crashes when this device is switched off.
The soundcard has a preference panel with a setting that I need to change back and forth every time I log in and out of OSX. (internal or external sync source).

Question:
Is there a way to script this? I've tried automator and applescript but when I change the setting in the panel it's not picked up by automator.
I found in the console log what value is changed (see screenshot) but I can't locate where.

I've found ways to script changing settings in the [System preferences][Sound] panel but there I can reference the 'tab group' and in the M-Audio panel I have no way of knowing how to reference it's tab group.

I have a background in programming but I'm just an amateur when it comes to digging deeper in OSX. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[screenshot of 2 panels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV7oh.png)

Comment: There may be other ways and this suggestion may not work, but it's a thought... http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#examples

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. I reminds me that I was kind of succesful in a similar way using the 'watch me do' recorder in Automator. But this also visually drags the mouse over the screen and clicks the button. I was hoping for a more elegant 'behind the screen' solution.

Comment: in the console, the log says "set clock source 4000000" or toggled to 4000001. I'm hoping there is a way to find out where this value is stored so that I can change it through a script instead of the panel.

Comment: I guess it would be in a `xxx.plist` file somewhere, but it's not certain the app would notice if you changed that file behind its back without using the GUI.

Comment: Say you thought the word `audio` might appear in the plist file, you could do `sudo find / -name "*.plist" -exec grep -i "audio" {} + 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Thank you! after some time I finally found the plist using grep and also found the value that changes. Unfortunately you were also right that the app does not notice when I change the file behind it's back. So it's back to square one..

Comment: Can you stop the app, change the value and restart?

Comment: I tried, but it does not load the new value when restarting. Really weird. It must be stored in RAM or something as long as the Mac is not powered off. Thanks for the suggestion though!